# tiles url mapping with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, tiles

I'm using tiles with spring boot, and want to mapping 2 url pattern

ex)

```
~~/something -> normal spring boot controller
~~/something.tiles -> tiles pattern
```

I checked each module works fine, but idont know how to map url pattern.

When i use Spring, i was configured dispatcherServlet setting in web.xml like this

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Tiles Dispatch Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.tiles.web.util.TilesDispatchServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Tiles Dispatch Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.tiles</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

but how can i configure it in spring boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `ServletRegistrationBean` annotated with `@Bean` in one of your `@Configuration` classes

```
   @Bean
   public ServletRegistrationBean tilesServletRegistrationBean() {
      return new ServletRegistrationBean(new TilesDispatchServlet(), "*.tiles");
   }
```